# Query result on peer1.org2 is INVALID

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

All of a sudden latest version 1.1.0-alpha, started throwing errors in bring the Hyperledger Fabric Samples - `first-network`, while running `./byfc.sh -m up`

```
2018-02-20 10:40:29.991 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Query result on peer1.org2 is INVALID !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================== ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ==================

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

Need help.. How to debug?

---

**Updates**

I had everything running using Fabric 1.1.0-alpha, when I tried sometime after Jan 26. Recently I wanted to try adding a new org to the network. So thought of re-doing from scratch, but now it's failing. Not able to proceed, which I had done it earlier, couple of times. Not sure what is wrong since yesterday, with latest fabric samples...

Cloned the source from `master` branch.

`Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`

`Node version v8.9.4`

`NPM version 5.6.0`

`cryptogen version 1.1.0-alpha`

`configtxlator version 1.1.0-alpha`

Removed old binaries (`/bin` folder) and docker containers and images, to start from scratch, but no luck:

`./byfn.sh -m down`

`docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`

`docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)`

`docker network prune`

I tried running `./byfn.sh`, using `-m`, also without, Same result.

`./byfn.sh generate`

`./byfn.sh up`

And,

`./byfn.sh -m generate`

`./byfn.sh -m up`

Comment: I believe this to be related to Docker install/version system issues. Queries should still run successfully throughout the exercise from the tutorial page. There is also a Troubleshooting section. Have you tried those pointers? http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#troubleshooting  see this error here as well: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5154

Comment: Thanks Amanda.. Jira task, is related to `writing your first app`, which I am able to complete without any errors, i.e., `http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0-alpha/write_first_app.html`. But when I run `building your first app`, i.e., `http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0-alpha/build_network.html`, my Test fails for `peer1.org2`. So far no luck..

Comment: i'm also naive to the hyperledger fabric. And i came across this situation couple of times. What i did is to cleanup all the mess and take a fresh start. this always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you checkout the right fabric-samples repo tag that matches the binaries version? The documentation for this was just updated serveral hours ago, so if you were referring to an earlier version of the documentation you might want to refresh:

> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html#download-platform-specific-binaries

Make sure you Checkout to the right tag. eg: after you clone, then cd to that folder, finally you git `git checkout v1.1.0-alpha`

then when running the `byfn.sh` script, you might need to use the `-m` option, e.g. `./byfn.sh -m generate

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.

I was following the steps from below links:

`http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0-alpha/samples.html#download-platform-specific-binaries`

I am able to setup `fabcar` successfully. But unable to run `first-network` successfully. Both the org's are up, but test failed.

Previously I had run `first-network` sample successfully, but using release version (v1.0.4), and not 1.1.0-alpha.

Answer (score 0):

With v1.1.0-rc1, I am able to execute the first-network successfully.

```
===================== Query on peer1.org2 on channel 'mychannel' is successful ===================== 
========= All GOOD, BYFN execution completed =========== 
 _____   _   _   ____   
| ____| | \ | | |  _ \  
|  _|   |  \| | | | | | 
| |___  | |\  | | |_| | 
|_____| |_| \_| |____/
```

I suspect, the error which I faced previously with v1.1.0-alpha, was just due to missing instruction in the tutorial, i.e., `git checkout {TAG}`. Now this has been updated correctly in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar error with Release 1.4.1

```
100
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Query result on peer1.org2 is INVALID !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================== ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ==================

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

I resolved it by following steps:

1. Removed fabric-samples directory
2. Run command in hyperledger directory

   ```
   curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 1.4.1 1.4.1 0.4.15
   ```
3. `./byfn.sh up -l node`

It is working fine.

```
90
===================== Query successful on peer1.org2 on channel 'mychannel' ===================== 

========= All GOOD, BYFN execution completed ===========
```